# Set the primary and secondary ips in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using **terraform** to create an instance with multiple ips in AWS. 
I specified a list of private_ips and made sure the one I wanted as primary was listed first, however it does not respect that order. Order doesn't change even when when I change the ips around. 
I also tried setting with **private_ip** for the primary ip and **private_ips** for secondary ips. However, I found out that the primary ip does not get listed when the instance is created. 
Is there a proper way to set the primary and secondary ips in terraform? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and I couldn't get around it so I ended up:

1. Apply terraform first without the secondary IP address.
2. Add the secondary IP address, and apply terraform.

Hope it helps.